# Image segmentation by background color - OpenCV Android

Tags: android, opencv

I'm trying to segment business cards and split them by background color to treat them as different regions of interest.

For example a card of this sort:
[image: Sample business card]

should be able to be to be split into two images as there are 2 background colors. Are there any suggestions on how to tackle this? I've tried doing some contour analysis which didn't turn out too successful.

Other example cards:
[image]

This card should give 3 segmentations, as there are three portions even though it's only 2 colors (though 2 colors will be okay).

[image]

The above card should give just one segmentation as it is just one background color.

I'm not trying to think of gradient backgrounds just yet.

Comment: SalGad or can someone help me in this matter, I really need to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876457/image-segmentation-using-segment-seeds-watershed-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how the other cards look, but if the images all are in that great quality, it should not be too hard.

In the example you posted, you could just collect the colors of the border pixels (most left column, most right column, first row, last row) and treat what you find as possible background colors. Perhaps check if there are enough pixels with roughly the same color. You need some kind of distance measuring. One easy solution is to just use the euclidean distance in RGB color space.

A more generic solution would be to find clusters in the color histograms of the whole image and treat every color (again with tolerance) that has more than x% of the overall pixel amount as a background color. But what you define as background depends on what you want to achieve and how your images look.

If you need further suggestions, you could post more images and tag what parts of the images you want to be detected as a background color and what parst not.

-

Edit: Your two new images also show the same pattern. Background colors occupy a big part of the image, there is no noise and there are no color gradients. So a simple approach could look like the following:

- Calculate the histogram of the image: see http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#calchist and http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html
- Find the most prominent colors in the histogram. If you do not want to iterate over the Mat yourself you can use minMaxLoc ( http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxloc) as shown in the calchist documentation (see above), and if the color takes up enough percentage of the pixel count save it and set the according bin in the histogram to zero. Repeat until your percentage is not reached any more. You will then have saved a list of the most prominent colors, your background colors.
- Threshold the image for every background color you have. See: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html
- On the resulting threadholded images find the corresponding region to every background color. See: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

If you have examples that do not work with this approach, just post them.

Comment: I've added a few more example cards. Can you also relate your answer more to OpenCV if possible?

Comment: Thanks @Dobi, I will try this out and let you know :)

Comment: Do you have any advice on what kind of threshold to use? I'm racking my mind on how to isolate each peak on the histogram on the image so I can get contours relating just to that peak

Comment: If your images are all as clear as your examples, your histogram peaks will be very narrow and high. Just experiment with it. My first guess would be: Use 16 bins per dimension in your histogram. Use every bin (of your 16^3) with its value higher than 0.3*number_of_pixels_in_image as bg color, and use a threshold with a tolerance of 16 color values difference for the segmentation of it.

Comment: It seems that the first image has a slight gradient in the background, and gives several peaks of bins... Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Ok. I did not see this in the first place. I only looked at the histogram of the second image, I guess. In that cases my approach is useless. Have you already tried usual contour finding like in this tutorial? http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html You just would have to add a parameter for the minimum size of the contours you want to keep. You can get the area with cv::contourArea ( http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#contourarea ) and divide it by the number of pixels in your image.

Comment: Yeah I did try the usual contour finding method, but it's difficult to identify which may be the backgrounds, as it may not give reliable contours for all types of cards. Your method did work beautifully for cards with linear colours though, thank you so much :) If there are any ideas for gradient colours, it will be super helpful

Comment: And I will be marking your answer right and passing you the bounty anyway because you've been really helpful so far

Comment: Thanks, that is very generous of you. :) But now I am also interested in really solving the problem. ;) Because of the new approach now I posted a new answer.

Comment: @TobiasHermann or can someone help me in this matter, I really need to do this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61876457/image-segmentation-using-segment-seeds-watershed-in-android

Answer (score 0):

As an approach for also finding backgrounds with color gradients in them, one could use canny. The following code (yes, not android, I know, but the result should be the same if you port it) works fine with the three example images you posted so far. If you have other images, that do not work with this, please let me know.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat src;
Mat src_gray;
int canny_thresh = 100;
int max_canny_thresh = 255;
int size_per_mill = 120;
int max_size_per_mill = 1000;
RNG rng(12345);

bool cmp_contour_area_less(const vector<Point>& lhs, const vector<Point>& rhs)
{
    return contourArea(lhs) < contourArea(rhs);
}

void Segment()
{
    Mat canny_output;
    vector<vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    Canny(src_gray, canny_output, canny_thresh, canny_thresh*2, 3);

    // Draw rectangle around canny image to also get regions touching the edges.
    rectangle(canny_output, Point(1, 1), Point(src.cols-2, src.rows-2), Scalar(255));
    namedWindow("Canny", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Canny", canny_output);

    // Find the contours.
    findContours(canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0));

    // Remove largest Contour, because it represents always the whole image.
    sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(), cmp_contour_area_less);
    contours.resize(contours.size()-1);
    reverse(contours.begin(), contours.end());

    // Maximum contour size.
    int image_pixels(src.cols * src.rows);
    cout << "image_pixels: " << image_pixels << "\n";

    // Filter the contours, leaving just large enough ones.
    vector<vector<Point> > background_contours;
    for(size_t i(0); i < contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        double area(contourArea(contours[i]));
        double min_size((size_per_mill / 1000.0) * image_pixels);
        if (area >= min_size)
        {
            cout << "Background contour " << i << ") area: " << area << "\n";
            background_contours.push_back(contours[i]);
        }
    }

    // Draw large contours.
    Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3);
    for(size_t i(0); i < background_contours.size(); ++i)
    {
        Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
        drawContours(drawing, background_contours, i, color, 1, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());
    }

    namedWindow("Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Contours", drawing);
}

void size_callback(int, void*)
{
    Segment();
}

void thresh_callback(int, void*)
{
    Segment();   
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        cout << "Please provide an image file.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    src = imread(argv[1]);

    cvtColor(src, src_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    blur(src_gray, src_gray, Size(3,3));

    namedWindow("Source", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("Source", src);

    if (!src.data)
    {
        cout << "Unable to load " << argv[1] << ".\n";
        return -2;
    }

    createTrackbar("Canny thresh:", "Source", &canny_thresh, max_canny_thresh, thresh_callback);
    createTrackbar("Size thresh:", "Source", &size_per_mill, max_size_per_mill, thresh_callback);

    Segment();
    waitKey(0);
}
```