# Cropping image based on background stripe colors with python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have an image that has large stripes in the background.

I would like to crop this image into separate images based on the background color.

Here is a [sample image](http://ornear.com/stripes.jpg) the stripes may vary in size and location.

Comment: What is the purpose of your task? Do you only process checkered images like this one?

Comment: The actual images have text in them, which are divided by the colors. I'm trying to OCR them with tesseract, but I need only the text in the area of the stripe, because the content is divided by the color areas. I've tried grabbing the most common color, but I'm not sure how to crop based on the color.

Comment: This is probably "hard" to do with PIL. You may want to look into opencv. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221668/image-segmentation-by-background-color-opencv-android) explains how to extract colored regions